# Marshalling the nested xml tags into multiple separate tags

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have a XML response coming from the api something like

```
<RootElement>
    <Account>
     <Address>
      <Name>xyz</Name>
     </Address>
     <Address>
      <Name>abc</Name>
     </Address>
    </Account>
    <Account>
     <Address>
      <Name>def</Name>
     </Address>
     <Address>
      <Name>pqr</Name>
     </Address>
   </Account>
</RootElement>
```

and the corresponding Java classes for the above representation as

```
@XmlRootElement(name="RootElement")
class RootElement {
  
  @XmlElement(name="Account")
  List<Account> account;

//corresponding getter and setter method
}
```

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Account")
class Account {

 @XmlElement(name="Address")
 List<Address> address;

//corresponding getter and setter method
}
```

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Address")
class Address {

 @XmlElement(name="Name")
 String name;

//corresponding getter and setter method

}
```

Here I want to marshall the XML response coming from API into this structure

```
<RootElement>
    <Account>
     <Address>
      <Name>xyz</Name>
     </Address>
    </Account>
    <Account>
     <Address>
      <Name>abc</Name>
     </Address>
    </Account>
    <Account>
     <Address>
      <Name>def</Name>
     </Address>
   </Account>
   <Account>
     <Address>
      <Name>pqr</Name>
     </Address>
   </Account>
</RootElement>
```

For marshalling the Java object, this the code I have added

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(CreateExemptionCertificate.class);
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    m.marshal(cc, sw);

    String result = sw.toString();
```

I want to split the inner Address tags into multiple Account tags.
How can this be achieved in Java, I tried marshalling but could not form the required XML structure.

Comment: You need to create new instance(s) of RootElement which would follow you requirement, i.e. for each inner address you would create a account / address pair. You would serialize the result of the transition.

Comment: @Michal do you mean to like loop through each Account object and depending upon the number of Address object, create new instance?

Comment: I would copy the existing RootObjects into new ones. And yes, during the copy process I would set-up the account / address members in a way that corresponds to your requirement.  My guess is that this is easier done while copying then on the original objects. Of course, if you manage to do it in-place (on the original objects) and do not need the original objects, that would work as well.

Comment: I would like to manipulate the existing RootElement object in such a way that it creates new Account object basis the number of Address object instead of creating another RootElement object altogether. Could you direct me towards any such links or references?

Comment: I do not think exactly that problem has been described somewhere. As I said, it could be done, but it is much easier done using the copy approach. I guess you have to figure out one of those on your own.